# How to get the id of a parent or closest fieldset?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="10">
  <h1>Select a color:</h1>
  <select name="color">
    <option>red</option>
    <option>blue</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();

$.each(fields, function (i, field) {
  var field_id = $(field.name).closest("fieldset").attr('id');
  $("#results").append('<a href="'+field_id+'">'+field.value+'</a>');
});
```

All I get is `undefined`?

When I do: `field.name`, it gives me "color". I want to be able to find the parent or closest fieldset that this form element belongs to.

I expect `field_id` to equal "10" in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I do: field.name, it gives me "color"*

Use

```
var field_id = $('[name=' + field.name+']').closest("fieldset").attr('id');
```

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you. (I will accept) Sort of a side question but can you point to tutorial/post (like a quickstart) on JS debugging (perhaps recommend tools?) because I find it a royal pain in the arse to debug JS. (e.g. I'll do a console.log() and I get [Object object] and firebug console is just a drop down after down and I have no idea what I'm looking at or where to start.) Appreciate the advice. Thanks again.

Comment: @feed_me_code, A good start [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code), [Debugging JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) and http://www.qtweb.net/pages/ibr9600.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Glad to know it's not just me. :)